# Why am I getting the pylint error: Value 'self.body' is unsubscriptable?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get the summary method the return the first 50 characters from the body.

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    # Title for the Blog
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    # Blog body
    body = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def summary(self):
        return self.body[:50]  # I get the error here
```

Answer (score 3):

Your linter is getting confused since it expects `self.body` to be an instance of `models.TextField`, which does not support subscripting. However, Django's ORM will in reality substitute `self.body` with a string, which does support subscripting. Django does a fair amount of magic with metaclassess to provide this interface, and unfortunately linters usually aren't smart enough to detect this.

Comment: Do PyLint and/or Django respect `typing.cast`? I'm wondering about something like `body: str = typing.cast(str, models.TextField())`.